# Rails token authentication and testing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, token

I'm trying to pass a token into rails and validate it, but am getting a strange "render" error. Additionally, I'm not sure how to pass the "Authentication: Token token=" header through the RSPEC controller test.

Here's the relevant code:

**/app/controllers/api_base_controller.rb**

```
# The authentication method in which I'm trying to set the @current_user
class ApiBaseController < RocketPants::Base

    private

        def authenticate_social  ## This is line 7 of the error below
            authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
              @current_customer = Customer.where(token: token).first
            end
        end
end
```

**/app/controllers/api/v1/customers_controller.rb**

```
# A simple method to "expose" (RocketPants' way of respond_with) the @current_customer from above
class Api::V1::CustomersController < ApiBaseController
    before_action :authenticate_social

  def fetch
        expose @current_customer
    end
end
```

**/spec/controllers/api/v1/customers_controller_spec.rb**

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::CustomersController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #fetch' do
    context '[Customer token exists]' do
      it 'returns the customer object' do
        @customer = FactoryGirl.create(:facebook_customer)
        get :fetch, version: 1  ## This is line 81 of the error below. Not sure how to pass token header
        expect(response).to be_singular_resource
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**The rspec error**

```
3) Api::V1::CustomersController GET #fetch [Customer token exists] returns the customer object
     Failure/Error: get :fetch, version: 1
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `render' for #<Api::V1::CustomersController:0x007f9b20c39430>
     # ./app/controllers/api_base_controller.rb:7:in `authenticate_social'
     # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/customers_controller_spec.rb:81:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've searched high and low, but still, nothing. Thoughts?

Comment: Please add the method `ApiBaseController#authenticate_social`  method from the stack trace `./app/controllers/api_base_controller.rb:7`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Are you saying to add it to my original post? Because it is there, unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed it when reading the question.